# how to change the textfield value when the button is clicked in uitableviewcell iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing a shopping app, in which i'm implementing a shopping cart. In my app, i need to increase the product quantity when the plus button is clicked and reduce the product quantity when the minus button is clicked. Here my problem is, when i click the plus button, all text field value is changing in the tableviewcell. Help me,below is
plus button action method

```
-(IBAction)plusBtn:(UIButton*)plus
{
    [self.tbleView beginUpdates];

    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[plus superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonIndexPath = [self.tbleView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

    plus.tag = clickedButtonIndexPath.row;
    quantity.tag = clickedButtonIndexPath.row;

    _curr =_curr+1;
    quantity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_curr];

    [self.tbleView endUpdates];
    [self.tbleView reloadData];
}
```

like this

[image]

getting..

[image]

Comment: please add code of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and plusButton action method

Comment: i had added the method now

Comment: do you have a custom cell or are you using [cell viewWithTag:xx] for  adding text to the quantity textfield?

Comment: @aravind Nair ya i'm using the quantity=(UITextField*)[cellVal viewWithTag:90];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can u check this functionality. it will useful for you. i hope it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];

     quantity =[NSMutableArray new];
     occu_list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Occupation", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six", @"seven", @"eight", nil];
     for(int i=0;i<[occu_list count];i++)
     {
         [quantity addObject:@"0"];
     }
     click_textView=[[UIView alloc]init];
     click_textView.frame=self.view.frame;
     [self.view addSubview:click_textView];
     [self tableviewone];
}

-(void)tableviewone
{
    tbl_view = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tbl_view.delegate = self;
    tbl_view.dataSource = self;
    tbl_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tbl_view.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor orangeColor]CGColor];
    tbl_view.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;
    tbl_view.layer.cornerRadius=5.0f;
    tbl_view.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    [click_textView addSubview:tbl_view];
}

-(IBAction)check_btn_action:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btntag=(UIButton*)sender;

    NSLog(@"%li",(long)btntag.tag);
    NSLog(@"%@",[quantity objectAtIndex:btntag.tag]);
    int ad=[[quantity objectAtIndex:btntag.tag]integerValue];
    ad=ad+1;
   [quantity removeObjectAtIndex:btntag.tag];
   [quantity insertObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",ad] atIndex:btntag.tag];
   [tbl_view reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write action method for your button and then inside that just use this one line of code for setting your value to the textfield:-

```
self.yourTxtFld.text=@"yourString"
```

Comment: thanks for answering,this is not my problem,here i having the textfileld and plus & minus button in the uitableviewcell,i want to change the textfield value when the plus or minus button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

Don`t write the Button action in ViewController,

write it in the CustomCell class.

example:

in the CustomCell.m

```
- (IBAction)plusButtonDidClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    int i = [self.textField.text intValue];

    i++;

    self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
}
```

Then back to the ViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```

It will be work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)plusBtn:(UIButton*)plus
{
   UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[plus superview] superview];
   _curr=_curr+1;
   UITextField *qty = (UITextField *) [clickedCell viewWithTag:90];
   qty.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",_curr];
}
```